# Does Linux work well with encrypted ntfs drives?

Tags: linux, ntfs, disk-encryption

What I want to do is to fully encrypt my external HDD.
My only system ATM is on Debian testing so I need to be able to set up the encryption from Linux.
My questions are, can that be done from Linux?
If I need to transfer the files to a friend, can I just plug in the USB, input the password and will his windows PC be able to read the encrypted filesystem?

Comment: If your only system is a Linux system, then why do you want to use NTFS in the first place, as opposed to a native Linux-compatible file system?

Comment: It is an external USB hard drive. I want to be able to connect it to my fathers PC. my friends PC's etc... while the drive itself is still encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

Linux doesn't support NTFS file-level encryption. Bitlocker using the recovery key sorta works but is still very new(look [here](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/outils/dislocker/download/) for more info). Windows in turn can't read LUKS-encrypted devices. If you need to share your encrypted drive between Windows and Linux, I'd recommend [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) or one of the other TrueCrypt forks.

Comment: Will my friends have to also install VeraCrypt on their machines?

Comment: Either that or they use VeraCrypt in portable mode, maybe from a small unencrypted partition of the disk